# working on hotel reservation system and I get stuck on check avaibility room

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

there is my db structure:

1. Rooms:
   roomId-roomName-roomCapacity
2. Reservation:
   rsId-rsroomId-date_in-date_out

I want to create a search function for searching available rooms.
I can't get the ones which are available, which are not booked for those days.
I have tried lots of things but till now can't solve this issue.
There is my latest code:

```
function search ($name, $date_in, $date_out) {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('Rooms');
    $this->db->join('Reservation', 'rooms.roomid = reservation.rsroomId', 'LEFT');
    $this->db->like('date_in', $date_in);
    $this->db->like('date_out', $date_out);
    $this->db->like('roomName', $name);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the CodeIgniter way to build a query, but I understand what you want to achieve. The raw query would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT  Rooms.*
FROM    Rooms
        LEFT JOIN Reservation
            ON Rooms.roomId = Reservation.rsroomId
                AND date_in < '$date_out' AND date_out > '$date_in'
WHERE   rsId IS NULL;
```

To select all overlapping reservations in the `JOIN ON` condition, you must compare the `date_in` of existing reservations with the `$date_out` of the desired reservation, and vice versa. If an existing reservation checks out before you want to check in, it does not overlap. If an existing reservation checks in after you want to check out, it does not overlap.

After carefully crafting these `JOIN ON` conditions to get the overlapping reservations, the `WHERE rsId IS NULL` condition ensures that you get only rooms for which there is no such existing overlapping reservation.

That last part is easy in CodeIgniter, but getting all the three `JOIN ON` conditions into `$this->db->join()` is going to be messy. The `like()` and `where()` functions automatically escape your values, but here you need to add this protection against SQL injection manually. Perhaps something like this:

```php
function search ($date_in, $date_out) {
    // Ensuring these values are safe in raw SQL:
    $date_in = $this->db->escape($date_in);
    $date_out = $this->db->escape($date_out);
    
    $joinCondition = 'rooms.roomid = reservation.rsroomId';
    $joinCondition .= " AND date_in < $date_out AND date_out > $date_in";
    
    $this->db->select('*')->from('Rooms');
    $this->db->join('Reservation', $joinCondition, 'LEFT');
    $this->db->where('rsId', NULL);
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
}
```

An alternative is to put question marks in the raw query, so CodeIgniter can escape your values via query bindings:

```php
function search ($date_in, $date_out) {
    $sql = "SELECT  Rooms.*
            FROM    Rooms
                    LEFT JOIN Reservation
                        ON Rooms.roomId = Reservation.rsroomId
                            AND date_in < ? AND date_out > ?
            WHERE   rsId IS NULL";
    $binds = [$date_out, $date_in];
    return $this->db->query($sql, $binds)->result_array();
}
```

Comment: Escaping condition from join to query also would be the answer. But the best practice is your answer. One more thing in my opinion that does it required to cast date type of the $date_in and $date_out?

Comment: @PranavBhatt it depends. If your `date_in` and `date_out` columns are defined as `DATE` type and if your `$date_in` and `$date_out` parameters **always** contain good values like `"2022-02-16"`, then you do not need conversion, but I added it for safety. If the values come from a form, then a hacker may put `"2022-02-16'; DROP TABLE Reservation;"` in your parameter and then all rooms will be free...

Comment: @PranavBhatt I had a look at the CodeIgniter user guide and changed my answer a little to use their escape function and show an alternative that uses the raw SQL query with parameter binding, which does the escaping for you.